# Run a mongoose query synchronously using async package

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I wanna check whether a username is existed or not. 
I have to run it synchronously.

```
function notExisted(string) {
    var username = '';

    //STEP 1: check if any user is existed with the givven username, and asign a value to username var.
    User.findOne({'username': string}, function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        req.flash('error', 'An error occured.');
        res.redirect("back");
      } else {
        if (!result === null) {
          username = result.username;
        } else {
          username = null;
        }
      }
    });

    // STEP 2: based on username varibale return false(if founded) or true(if not founded)
    // if any user has founded, the username variable would be the username. Otherwise it would be null.
    if (username === null) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

As you see step 1 and 2 should run one after another.
Do you know how to run that 2 steps synchronously by [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) library or any better approach?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"I have to run it synchronously"_. Why? Short answer: you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code, I have not tested, but this is the way to use the async module for waterfall: -

```
let async = require('async');
async.waterfall([
     function(callback) {
          User.findOne({'username': string}, function (err, result) {
               if (err) {
                    callback( true, null);
               } else {
                    if (!result === null) {
                         username = result.username;
                    } else {
                         username = null;
                    }
                    callback( null, username);
               }
          });
     },
     function (username, callback) {
          if (username === null) {
               callback( null, true)
          } else {
               callback( null, false)
          }
     }
], function (err, result) {

     if (err) {
          req.flash('error', 'An error occured.');
          res.redirect("back");
     } else {
          console.log(result);// gives you true / false
     }
})
```

Comment: Or best way to is to have middleware for checking username, in this way the complexity in your main code will be less.